# How do I loop through a complicated array of JSON objects with arrays inside it and dynamic keys?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

How do I loop through this `filteredResults` observableArray given that all the first keys e.g. Basic Information and Guarantees and Debt Subordination are dynamic and each key is a reference to an array of objects. All the keys inside this object on the other hand are known.

```
  self.filteredResults = ko.observableArray([
  {
    "Basic Information": [
      {
        "nodeId": "8",
        "path": "Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
        "tooltip": "Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
        "resultLabel": "Active Bookrunners",
        "propertyClassType": "multiselect"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "12",
        "path": "Advisors / Auditors",
        "tooltip": "Advisors / Auditors",
        "resultLabel": "Auditors",
        "propertyClassType": "multiselect"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "442",
        "path": "Pricing / Amount",
        "tooltip": "Pricing / Amount",
        "resultLabel": "Amount",
        "propertyClassType": "millions"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Guarantees and Debt Subordination": [
      {
        "nodeId": "70",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "propertyClassType": "select"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "71",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "propertyClassType": "boolean"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "80",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "propertyClassType": "select"
      }
    ]
  }]);
```

This is what I've tried so far in my template. I can get the first keys and the first object within the array of objects but it only ever prints the first one.

```
<ul class="pull-left list-group index-search-results">
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: filteredResults, as: 'result'} -->

         <!--ko foreach: {data: Object.keys(result), as: 'groupHeader'}-->

            <li data-bind="text: groupHeader" class="nav-header disabled "></li>

            <!--ko foreach: {data: result[groupHeader], as: 'resultNode' }-->

                 <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(resultNode, null, 2)"></pre>

            <!--/ko -->
         <!--/ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

This is what it prints:

```
Basic Information
{
  "propertyClassId": "8",
  "path": "Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
  "tooltip": "Basic Information / Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
  "resultLabel": "Active Bookrunners",
  "propertyClassType": "multiselect"
}
Guarantees and Debt Subordination
{
  "propertyClassId": "70",
  "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
  "tooltip": "Guarantees and Debt Subordination / Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
  "resultLabel": "Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
  "propertyClassType": "select"
}
```

As you can see it is missing the last two objects for each key.

What am I missing here?

If I do:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(filteredResults, null, 2)"></pre>
```

It prints the entire list.

If I do under the first foreach loop:

```
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

It prints only the key with one object.

Answer (score 0):

It works here:

```js
self = {}; 
self.filteredResults = ko.observableArray([
  {
    "Basic Information": [
      {
        "nodeId": "8",
        "path": "Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
        "tooltip": "Bookrunners / Active Bookrunners",
        "resultLabel": "Active Bookrunners",
        "propertyClassType": "multiselect"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "12",
        "path": "Advisors / Auditors",
        "tooltip": "Advisors / Auditors",
        "resultLabel": "Auditors",
        "propertyClassType": "multiselect"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "442",
        "path": "Pricing / Amount",
        "tooltip": "Pricing / Amount",
        "resultLabel": "Amount",
        "propertyClassType": "millions"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Guarantees and Debt Subordination": [
      {
        "nodeId": "70",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Notes Guaranteed?",
        "propertyClassType": "select"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "71",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Guarantees Secured?",
        "propertyClassType": "boolean"
      },
      {
        "nodeId": "80",
        "path": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "tooltip": "Guarantees / Overview of the Guarantees / Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "resultLabel": "Are the Guarantees Direct or Indirect?",
        "propertyClassType": "select"
      }
    ]
  }]);  

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul class="pull-left list-group index-search-results">
    <!-- ko foreach: {data: filteredResults, as: 'result'} -->

         <!--ko foreach: {data: Object.keys(result), as: 'groupHeader'}-->

            <li data-bind="text: groupHeader" class="nav-header disabled "></li>

            <!--ko foreach: {data: result[groupHeader], as: 'resultNode' }-->

                 <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(resultNode, null, 2)"></pre>

            <!--/ko -->
         <!--/ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```